# Cocoa - NSError description coming from nowhere

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nserror

I have this piece of code :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response 
{
    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(statusCode)]) {

        int statusCode = [((NSHTTPURLResponse*)response) statusCode];
        if (statusCode >= 400) {
            NSError* statusError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Server connection error" code:statusCode userInfo:nil];
            [self connection:connection didFailWithError:statusError];
        }
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error 
{
NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

That gives for a missing page :

--> The operation couldn’t be completed. (Server connection error error 404.)

From where does that **description** (localized or not) comes from ?
I've just initialized the NSError with a code and a custom meaningless domain string...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That error message means that your online resource cannot be found by the server.

For example: http://www.google.com/notthepageyourelookingfor.

[HTTP 404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) - Wikipedia

If you're asking where the error message originates, it ought to break down like this:

- `localizedDescription`:

  > The operation couldn't be completed ()

By default this method returns the object in the user info dictionary for the key [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSLocalizedDescriptionKey). If the user info dictionary doesn’t contain a value for [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSLocalizedDescriptionKey), a default string is constructed from the domain and code.
NSLocalizedDescriptionKey is a localized string representation of the error that, if present, will be returned by localizedDescription.
Available in Mac OS X v10.2 and later. Declared in NSError.h.

- `errWithDomain:@"Server connection error"`:

  > Server connection error
- `code:statusCode`:

  > error 404

Comment: Can't be found by the *server*. It is not the app's fault. Note that.

Comment: @Oliver: I added some more information about the origin of the localized message. Otherwise, I can't break it down any further. You're supplying most of the error message, and telling the error to fill in the rest.

Comment: @Patrick Perini : do you mean that the constructor of NSError knows what to show when the code is 404 ? What about the domain ? What should I put in there to work in a good way ?

Answer (score 1):

> The operation couldn’t be completed.

That is a standard POSIX error. Your domain and error code are just appended to the actual error message to determine the error's origin. Usually, a reverse-DNS style domain is used, like `com.developer.package`.

Comment: Great. But the question is from where does the error message comes from.